# Port can't be connected in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I using the port 4200 in my angular, and port 3000 for my nodejs, when i am running angular the nodejs does not work. Connection refused problem occurred.
What i do? Plz answer my question

Comment: show us your log message

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED vendor.bundle.js:53304 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it supposed to work.

Running Angular on 4200 port is the CLI's ability for live reload & All, it doesn't create the distribution folder or the dist.

This is how it should work

1. you create the dist folder [Html,CSS,JS]
2. You write an express code in Node JS to serve the dist directory or index.html
3. You copy the dist to the public accessible folder in node JS
4. When you hit localhost:3000 then & Only then Node JS as well as Angular will run.

Example :

create 1 folder server
In it write app.js with this code.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(logger('dev
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html
});
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});
if (app.get('env== 'development')
{
app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example listening on port 3000!');
});
}
else{
app.listen(8080, function () {
console.log('Example listening on port 8080!');
});
}
module.exports = app;
```

This snippet assumes that u have installed  cookie-parser body-parser morgan.

So basically any request redirects to index.html which is the starting point of the Angular 2 App.

Now when u do

```
node app.js
```

your angular app will be served through Node JS & Express